# if(isset($_POST['submit'])) function is not set when working with radio buttons

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

Okay, first off I apologise if this question has been answered before but because of my lack in php knowledge I do not actually fully know what the problem is.

My `$_POST['submit']` does not appear to be set even after the submit button is clicked. I have tried this method before but with text fields, so I'm assuming I am doing something wrong with the configuration of the radio buttons. The way I know its not getting through `isset()` is because it is not echoing out "in `isset`" therefore can not reach the rest of my code. Also I have tried replacing `$_POST['submit']` with `$_POST['onoff']` but both return the same result.

```
function getRadioState()
{
    global $ac;
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo "in isset";
        $selected_radio = $_POST['onoff'];
        if ($selected_radio == 'On') {
            $ac = 1;
        } else if($selected_radio == 'Off') {
            $ac = 0;
        }
    }   
}
```

and here is my html code:

```
<form>
    On: <input type="radio" name="onoff" value="On"><br>
    Off: <input type="radio" name="onoff" value="Off"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Thank you in advance for any responses helping to answer my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because form defaults to GET when omitting the method.

Use `<form method="post">`

---

***Sidenote:*** Omitting the action defaults to self, should that be the intention.

It's the same as doing `action=""`

Answer (score 0):

1. Where you calling this function function getRadioState(){ ???
2. You have to save the page extension in php

And,

3.form method to POST

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
```

In test.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "in isset";
    $selected_radio = $_POST['onoff'];
    if($selected_radio == 'On'){
        $ac = 1;
    }else if($selected_radio == 'Off'){
        $ac = 0;
    }
}
```